# Deploying ear file to IBM WEBSPHERE8 with wsadmin.sh

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, wsadmin

I am new to Websphere and I found many answers for `*.ear` file deployment. Most of them use format similar to "

```
./wsadmin.sh -host vmllkb056933n.myspace.com -port 5000 -c '$AdminApp> install /apps/test-app.ear'
```

I am always getting errors like:

> *WASX8011W: AdminTask object is not available. WASX7015E: Exception running command: "$AdminApp install /apps/cdm-fi.ear"; exception
>   information: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7206W: The
>   application management service is not running. Application management
>   commands will not run.*

I am in a **RHEL 6** Environment and runing **IBM Websphere 8.5.5.3**

What is the easiest way to deploy ear file to IBM Websphere 8.5.5

Comment: Is the deployment manager started?  `./startManager.sh`   See this link for more details: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/tasks/tsrwasaixsolaris.htm%23tsrwasaixsolaris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your are using the deployment manager wsadmin.sh and that the dmgr process is running. Also the port you reference should be the SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS of the dmgr. Referencing the cluster or server name in a federated environment tells the dmgr where to put the code, as in the two examples below.

```
$AdminApp install "myapp.ear" {-cluster clusterName}
```

or

```
$AdminApp install app_server_root/installableApps/DynaCacheEsi.ear
{-appname MyApp -cell myCell -node myNode -server server1
-filepermission .*\\.jsp=777#.*\\.xml=755}
```

Don't forget to save and syncnodes. As in the jython below.

```
AdminConfig.save()

AdminNodeManagement.syncActiveNodes()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**Syntax :**

```
installApp $earFile $appName $destinationDir $serverName $nodeName $cellName $wasprofile
```